# Updating status bar appearance by toggling between lightContent and default using UIbutton

Tags: xcode, swift

I am making an app which allows users to change the theme, eg. changing the background colour. Assuming I have a button, when click, toggles the change in background colour.

Eg. in code:

```
@IBAction func floodLightAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    previousFloodlightOption = loadFloodlightOption()

    if previousFloodlightOption {

        print("OFF")

        saveFloodlightOption(false)

        // configure theme for themeViewController:

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .Default

        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()

        configureFloodlight(false)


    } else {

        print("ONN")

        saveFloodlightOption(true)

        // configure theme for themeViewController:

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent

        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()

        configureFloodlight(true)

    }
```

However, setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() does not seem to update the status bar style when the button is pressed. I have a few custom functions which are explained below.

My custom save func:

```
saveFloodlightOption(bool: Bool)
```

- This saves a boolean value using NSUserDefaults.

My theme configuration func:

```
configureFloodLight(bool: Bool)
```

- This just change objects' colour in the view controller based on the theme picked.

I hope I gave enough information, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set `View Controller Based Status bar appearance` to `false` in your info.plist?

[View Controller Based status bar appearance](http://rshankar.com/how-to-customize-status-bar-in-ios/)

Comment: Hi I have one more issue actually. How come override preferredStatusBarStyle does not work? For example: override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        
        if previousFloodlightOption {
            
            return UIStatusBarStyle.Default
            
        } else {
            
            return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
            
        }
        
    }